# Get HTTP Request Header Key Value into Conditional Check

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I've created a Logic App in the Azure Portal. It's triggered by an HTTP POST and in that POST I have set a Key called "jmb_private_key".  After the Logic App receives the HTTP Request I've placed a Conditional which I want to check for the Key.

Checking for `Header CONTAINS 'myvalue'` does not work.
I want to check `Header.Keys['jmb_private_key'] EQUALS 'myvalue'` but I don't know how that is done.

[image]

When I check the run of the Logic App, I see the correct JSON payload was delivered, but condition was not met, even though the correct value is in the JSON.

[image]

Comment: This should work: `@triggerOutputs()?['headers']?['jmb_private_key']`. You need to switch to **code view**

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Thanks to @Thomas for the answer in comments above.

Switch the Logic App Designer to Code View and then replace the Conditional code with something like this:

```
            "expression": {
                "and": [
                    {
                        "equals": [
                            "@triggerOutputs()?['headers']?['jmb_private_key']",
                            "yourkeyvalue"
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
```