# Error by reading Header values from Logic App HTTP Request

Tags: azure-logic-apps

In a if condition I tried to get a header value (secret key) I'am sending to the Logic App.

The following code is used to get the secret from the header (In this example i have parsed it before)

`@body('Parse_Header_from_HTTP_Request')?['headers']?['Secret']`

I have also tried the solution from this answered question:
[Azure Logic Apps : Get HTTP Request Header Key Value into Conditional Check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50238995/azure-logic-apps-get-http-request-header-key-value-into-conditional-check)

The variable is null if I check it on the Run History.

Comment: Can you show the run details ?

Comment: If it is a header you won't find it in the body... but you can get your header like that: `@triggerOutputs()?['headers']?['Secret']`

Comment: Any process now?

Comment: @triggerOutputs()?['headers']?['Secret'] with this i didn't found the values. The only way was to parse the value with the solution from @joeyCai

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, I do not know how you parse your header before. 
Here I use `Parse Json` to achieve, you could refer to the screenshot as below:

[image]

After setting `body('Parse_Json')?['name']` to get name value, the output is as below:

[image]

As you have said, you have parsed the header after http request. So, after parsing headers, the value is from `parse_json`, while you refer to the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50238995/azure-logic-apps-get-http-request-header-key-value-into-conditional-check) you provided which value is from http request header.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Working for me, i have parsed it with the header.